Movie with a scene where animal robots were hunting humans
I was around 6-8 years old when I saw this movie 10 years ago, and I remember seeing alot of humans scattered around a mixture of plains and forests at night. Some locked themselves inside an underground cage, thinking they would be safe. But a (robot?) animal used its tail to grab one of the humans through the ground. Chased until sunrise.
It is similar to the scene from The Maze Runner, where grievers attack the glade, but with more cages and more humans.

So, just to be clear, you're definitely not thinking of this scene from The Maze Runner...? And if not, how about the two sequels; have you seen either/both of them...?
